# OCaml: Can't find version

Tags: ocaml, opam

When I enter `ocaml --version` it returns

```
/usr/bin/ocaml: unknown option '--version'.
```

I installed it using OPAM and ran the instructions

opam init
eval $(opam env)
eval `opam env`
opam switch create 4.07.0

and everything seemed to go fine.  Entering `which ocaml` returns a correct-looking path.  And when entering a terminal session it seems to work fine.  I don't see this error mentioned anywhere when I search for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml tools are weird and usually do not follow the POSIX guidelines of using double dashes for command line options. At this point probably for historic reasons and because the standard `Arg` module parses command line arguments this way. In any case, this will do the trick:

```
ocaml -version
```